# Software to monitor certain directories in a web view

Tags: 20.04

So I am out of luck googling that's why I thought I would ask here. I look for a software that let's me visualize certain directories (local would be fine for now, NAS would be great) for a ubuntu server that lets me

- have a nice web view of all folders
- shows me some data on when the directory was created / changed / read the last time
- can alert me when the directory crosses some size threshold
- shows me additional metadata (that i can enter manually - like who is responsible for this directory)
- ideally lets me also move / delete this directory in the web frontend

Maybe someone of you can point me in the right direction :) Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I know it doesn't Fill out all your Requirements, but personally i use [Filebrowser](https://github.com/filebrowser/filebrowser). It's Really Simple and Easy To use.
It can Display you the Last Date of Modification and Provide an Simple Web view of all Folders you want.
You also have an Simple User-Management to Give People only Access to Folders they are allowed to edit.

The catch for me was the Easy Drag & Drop Upload, 1 click Download and the Build in Editor

As far as i know you have no option for additional Metadata and No Alerting. For me it also was missing some Features, but it can be a good Compromise.
(Also you need Docker to run it)